# Проблемы с выводом в IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Проблема, ребята, состоит в следующем: правило CSS `'margin auto'` вместе с `'position absolute'` не работает в IE7. Проблема именно в IE7, во всех других браузерах все работает отлично. У меня есть родительский элемент с `'position relative'`, он содержит ребенка с `'position absolute'`. Мне нужно выровнять элемент c `'position absolute'` по отношению к левой и правой стороне родительского элемента.

```
.header {
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      height: 341px;
}

.block-up {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background: #da251c;
  height: 341px;
}

.block-down {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background:  #585453;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 341px;
}

/*problem areas*/

.header-content {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 493px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 341px;
}
/*problem areas*/

.header-content-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 162px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 341px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<div class="header">
  <div class="block-up">
  </div>
  <div class="block-down">
  </div>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-box">
    </div>
    <div class="header-content-box">
    </div>
    <div class="header-content-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @antoantoanto, а подобная некрофилия (вёрстка под IE7) имеет под собой какие-либо веские основания? Это жёсткое требование заказчика, которое вообще никак нельзя обойти? Если нет, то забейте на поддержку браузера, которому уже почти 10 лет, оно того не стоит.

Comment: если уже нет возможности не делать для ие7 - тогда <!--[if IE 7]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->